# Spring cannot read from property file

Tags: spring, properties

have a class which is annotated with @Service, trying to read a property using values, the value always comes as zero

```
@Service
public class custom implements Conditional
{
@Value("${test.property}")
private boolean properttyValue;

}


#test.properties 
test.property= true
```

If i provide any non existent value in @Value, it throws an error , which means property is loaded,

Any idea whats wrong ?

Comment: Make sure that you class is being picked up by your main class `@ComponentScan`. Is it?

Comment: yes, the other class in the same package works fine..

Answer (score 0):

This is because test.propeties not in the class path. If you are using Spring boot use `-Dspring.config.location` to specify external configurations. You can do this using the following ways

```
-Dspring.config.location=your/config/dir/
-Dspring.config.location=classpath:pro1.properties,classpath:prop2.properties
```

If you are not using Spring boot, this can be done using

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:test.properties")
public class PropertiesWithJavaConfig {
    //...
}

@Configuration
@PropertySource({ 
  "classpath:test.properties"
})
public class PropertiesWithJavaConfig {
    //...
}
```

For external file "file:/" can be used instead of classpath e.g. `file:./,file:./config/`

Comment: i dont think thts the reason, since i have a similar file in same package, for which spring is able to load, only difference is, this implements Conditional - edited the question